# Java using ZMQ (and Eve EMDR)

Tags: java, zeromq

I'm trying to connect to eve EMDR using ZMQ in java, and I just get this error, any ideas?

http://eve-market-data-relay.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#java

Code:   https://gist.github.com/Sparcster/d140654cd157c73e0957

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Multimap
    at zmq.Reaper.<init>(Reaper.java:49)
    at zmq.Ctx.create_socket(Ctx.java:270)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.<init>(ZMQ.java:362)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.socket(ZMQ.java:311)
    at spacevac.Spacevac.main(Spacevac.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Multimap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
Java Result: 1
```

Also: I'm using JeroMQ instead of JZMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it is related to the new use of the Guava library.  Adding guava to the dependency pulls and the eclass path in the maven.xml file fixes these errors, according to (1) https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/174 and (2) https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/176.  You also may have a stale Ant build.xml, and might need to blow that away and regenerate it, if that is what you are using.